# Injecting generic data model with CDI/WELD

Tags: java, generics, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, cdi

I have problem with generics and CDI/WELD on GlassFish 3.1.2. I have these classes:

This is abstract bean which holds reference to JPA entity.

```
public abstract class AbstractViewBean<T extends Serializable> implements ISelectableBean {

    ...        

    private T viewObject;

    ...
}
```

Then I have abstract class for my JSF beans/pages, where I want inject TableLazyDataModel

```
public abstract class AbstractListPageAction<T extends AbstractViewBean<K>, K extends
        Serializable> {

    ...
    @Inject
    private TableLazyDataModel<T, K> dataModel;
    ...
}
```

TableLazyDataModel:

```
public class TableLazyDataModel<T extends AbstractViewBean<K>, K extends Serializable>
        extends LazyDataModel<T> {
    ...
}
```

If I want deploy application, I get:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [TableLazyDataModel<UserViewBean, CcalPracovnik>] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private cz.wf.ui.component.page.AbstractListPageAction.dataModel]
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:311)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:280)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:143)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:163)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:382)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:367)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:379)
at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:199)
```

If i remove *extends Serializable* from AbstractViewBean and from other classes:

```
public abstract class AbstractViewBean<T> implements ISelectableBean {

    ...        

    private T viewObject;

    ...
}

public abstract class AbstractListPageAction<T extends AbstractViewBean<K>, K> {

    ...
    @Inject
    private TableLazyDataModel<T, K> dataModel;
    ...
}
```

Everithing works fine. But why?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I updated WELD version of weld-osgi-bundle.jar to 1.1.11, but with no effect.

Comment: I would recommend you choose a tag to replace with java, so this question gets more attention.